# Python: how to print a .lbl file on Zebra printer?

Tags: python, zebra-printers

I have a Zebra Network printer, and I need to print different labels, with variable informations (for example: the date). I created all the labels with Zebra Designer and saved them as .lbl files.
I want to print them from a python interface, with a modification for the variable information

How can I do that?

I know how to edit and print ZPL code, but I want to use the .lbl files so that a non-programmer can easily create a new label.

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "10.4.29.158"
port = 9100
try:
    mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
    mysocket.send(b"^XA^FX^FDThis is a test^FS^XZ")#using bytes
    mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
    print("Error with the connection")
```

Comment: I know nothing about zebra printers. Given that you say they are network-attached, I assume the code you have shown is opening a socket and sending some data to a printer. I can only imagine you want to read the contents of a `.lbl` file and send that instead? Is that your question? If so `lbl = open('SomeFile.lbl', 'rb').read()` and then `mysocket.sendall(lbl)`

Comment: Your real question is how to insert runtime values in ZPL code, isn't it!?

Comment: The project is: a user create a mask in a label designing software, with some variable elements (for example: the date) and save as .lbl file. Then a python script read that mask, writes the date in the variable field, and send it to a printer. With open(file,'rb').read() I only get gibberish content, and can't adjust the variable.

Comment: I still know nothing about zebras. What happens if you use your normal program to create a label but put some known placeholder string in the file where you want a variable. E.g. you want to print a name, so in your normal software you create a label with name **FUNKYNAME**. Can you then see **FUNKYNAME** in the label file and replace it? So read `lbl` per my previous comment then try `if 'FUNKYNAME' in lbl:`

Comment: When your file content is not plain (ZPL) text, then you can't just save it as .lbl in your label editor because it seems to be a propietary format of that software. What you have to do is, print it to a plain text/file printer!

Comment: Reading the .lbl file only give gibberish content, I can't find the FUNKYNAME. Indeed,.lbl is a proprietary format used by Zebra Designer or NiceLabel.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new printer to your Windows system:

1. Open the start menu, type `printer` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Click `Add a printer or scanner`
   [image: Add printer or scanner]
3. Wait a a few moments until the message `The printer that I want isn't listed` appears, then click on it
   [image: The printer that I want isn't listed]
4. In the next dialog select `Add a local printer...` and click `Next`
   [image: Add a local printer...]
5. Then open the dropdown menu for exisiting ports, select `FILE: ...` and click `Next`
   [image: Choose a printer port]
6. In the next screen on the left side select `Generic`, on the right side select `Generic / Text Only`, then click `Next`
   [image: Generic text only printer]
7. Give the printer a name of your choice or keep the default, then click `Next`
8. Select if the printer needs to be shared or not, and click `Next`
9. If asked, don't select the printer as default, and click `Finish`

Now you can use this printer in your label design software to create plain text files containing the ZPL code. Load these files in your python app and replace the search strings with the desired content!

For further tests with the ZPL files you can use the online service [Labelary](http://labelary.com/viewer.html).